# Ayuda con ggplot y Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

En R normal genere un gráfico muy sencillo con ggplot que me gustaría mostrar en Shiny pero no logro hacer que se vea y no se cuál sea el error.

Afuera del Server declaró el plot pero no lo sé usar. Así es el código:

```
mydat <- read.csv(file = "queryCoca.csv")
datos = as.data.frame(mydat)

ventasMes <- tapply(datos$total_price, datos$aniomes, sum)
ventasMes <- as.data.frame(ventasMes)
ventasMes["Aniomes"]<-rownames(ventasMes)

plotVentas <- ggplot(ventasMes, aes(Aniomes, ventasMes, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(colour="#000099") +
  geom_line(colour="#000099")
```

Obteniendo la siguiente gráfica: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ya que lo quiero integrar en el server no lo logro:

```
server<-function(input, output, session){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data<-ggplot(ventasMes, aes(Aniomes, ventasMes, group = 1)) +
      geom_point(colour="#000099") +
      geom_line(colour="#000099")
    print(data)
  })

}
```

No tengo ningún resultado. 
Alguna ayuda?

Comment: si todo esta bien con tu ui funcionara si borras el "print(data)" y solo escribes "data" en su lugar. También puedes compartir tu ui

Answer (score 0):

Algunos datos y comentarios con respecto a tu pregunta:

- En principio pareciera que el problema está en hacer `data<-ggplot(v...`  ya que `renderPlot` debiera retornar el objeto `plot` directamente  y al asignarlo a la variable `data` no lo haces. Prueba retornando `data` o directamente `ggplot(...`
- Has implementado la función `ui` para definir la interfaz?
- Has llamado a `shinyApp(ui, server)` al final de tu Script?
- Has renombrado el script como `app.R` para que eventualmente `RStudio`lo detecte como una aplicación shinny

Por las dudas este es el esqueleto básico de una app Shinny similar a tu pregunta.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title=h4("Prueba de GGplot + Shinny", align="center")),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
)

server<-function(input, output, session){

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, group = 1)) +
            geom_point(colour="#000099") +
            geom_line(colour="#000099")
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]